# How does mvn dependency:analyze work?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Can someone let me know how does `mvn dependency:analyze` work ? An output of `mvn dependency:analyze` in one of my project shows

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[WARNING]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
...
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:test
[WARNING]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
```

Can some one let me know the following -

- What does `Used undeclared dependencies found` denote? Does it mean that this is not declared in `pom.xml` `dependencies` but getting used in code and is included via some transitive dependencies?
- Does `Unused declared dependencies found` check only for the `dependencies` declared in `pom.xml` or it checks transitive dependencies as well?

Maven Version - 3.5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does Used undeclared dependencies found denote? Does it mean that this is not declared in pom.xml dependencies but getting used in code and is included via some transitive dependencies?

Exactly!

> Does Unused declared dependencies found check only for the dependencies declared in pom.xml or it checks transitive dependencies as well?

Declared dependencies are the dependencies that are declared in *your* POM. So the plugin does not include transitive dependencies in its check.

Note, that the plugin does a byte-code analysis by default, which is problematic with dependencies that are only used with constants or annotations. This can lead to false reports in some situations. See the [FAQ](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/faq.html#unused) for details.

Comment: What does `usedDependencies` flag denote in the FAQ you shared? I have also seen https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html .  But it is still not clear to me. Does this mean that ignore the result of `Unused declared dependencies` ?

Comment: With the `usedDependencies`-parameter you can tell the plugin dependencies that are always to be treated as used, even if the bytecode-analysis found it wasn't used. This is sometimes useful to avoid incorrect reports.

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly, maven use the WebASM framework to analyze bytecode and check is lib used or not. Don't trust it, because sometimes maven thinks that lib (dependency) is not used, but it is.

Comment: So, I agree that there are some issues and false positives from the analysis. What do you recommend to use instead?

Answer (score -3):

This can be easily fixed with by adding ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies in the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
                    <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>
                </ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```