# Why does maven compiler plugin fail if unused 2nd level dependency jar(s) are not found

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, maven-compiler-plugin

I have projects with dependencies shown below:

WebApp > Level1 Dependency > Level2 dependency

Lets say that

- WebApp code uses only classes in Level1 dependency jar
- Both level1 and level2 dependencies are included with compile scope.
- Level1 jar in local repository. I deleted Level2 from local repository.

`mvn compile` fails with error
`Could not find artifact com.example:mydeplevel2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

I understand that jar/war packaging plugins need to traverse the whole hierarchy to be able to determine the transitive dependencies.

But why does compiler plugin error out? After all, even if all level2 dependencies were satisfied, I only see MyWebApp.class built in target folder. I could build MyWebApp.class with javac -cp MyWebApp.java.

Comment: You tell Maven that you need "level2 dependency" to compile and Maven tells you that it cannot compile without it. Not sure what's so surprising about that.

Comment: @Marvin, question was whether it could work without the missing jar. Below answer clarfies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state that, for your project:

> WebApp code uses only classes in Level1 dependency jar

Maven doesn't make that assumption, and it doesn't hold for many real projects. Maven ensures the transitive closure of the dependencies are present when compiling, and doesn't attempt to identify any unnecessary dependencies.

[`mvn dependency:analyze`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315863/how-does-mvn-dependencyanalyze-work) is a good way to confirm whether or not all direct dependencies are listed, but Maven doesn't assume that your project passes this check.

Comment: Yes, just realized that m-c-p does not try to work with jars it can find. It could have done that, but thats not the model it is designed with as you said.